# What are the options for implementing a "plugin" to an Android app?

Tags: android, plugins

Note that I am not asking about plugins to the development environment.  I am not an Android developer, but I am consulting with one -- "plugin" is their term.  I know that the plugins are developed and distributed separately from the base application.  Can the base app "load" another app and execute it directly?  Can a base app start and transfer state and control to another app?  Are there standard means by which a base app could validate a presumed plugin before using it?

Comment: "Can the base app "load" another app and execute it directly?" -- that would depend a lot on what you mean by "load" and "execute it directly". "Can a base app start and transfer state and control to another app?" -- an app can start another app. Beyond that, we would need more clarity on what constitutes "transfer state and control". "Are there standard means by which a base app could validate a presumed plugin before using it?" -- that depends a lot on what you mean by "validate" and what form the "plugin" takes.

Comment: Things like plugins for desktop browsers execute within the browser's process. Android has technical support for that sort of thing, but app distribution sites (like the Play Store) may prohibit it -- please consult with a qualified attorney. Android has a rich set of inter-process communications (IPC) options, and so some apps support "plugins" in the form of other apps that are installed on the same device, and the main and plugin apps then communicate.

Comment: Thanks.  What I meant by "load and execute directly" is something like a Linux exec where a process imports some other "program's" code into its memory space and then jumps or branches into that code (as opposed to making some kind of remote call).

Comment: What I meant by "transfer state and control" would be that after starting another app, some data/context could be supplied to the other app (which I assume could be done by IPC) and that the other app could be told to execute (which I guess is true since one app can "start" another app).

Comment: When I asked about "validating" another app, I meant an attempt to check that the other app is authentic or is an app that is known to work or be approved to work with the first app.  For example, the first app may be trying to use a second app as a "plugin", but only certain plugins from certain vendors should be allowed.  I am being a little vague with some of this stuff since I don't know all the capabilities and terminology in the Android world :).

Comment: "What I meant by "load and execute directly" is something like a Linux exec where a process imports some other "program's" code into its memory space and then jumps or branches into that code (as opposed to making some kind of remote call)" -- while Android has something like that, it is banned by the Play Store and perhaps other app distribution channels, as it is difficult to secure properly.

Comment: With regards to validation, if the other app is indeed an installed app, there are ways you can confirm that it was signed by a known good signing key, one that you get from the vendor (or obtain yourself from a presumed-good copy of the app). [This pair of sample apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding/SigCheck) is a bit old but demonstrate IPC where the client verifies the signature of the other app.